# Kummer sequence for "affine" elliptic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve defined over a number field $k$. Let $D$ be a reduced separable divisor on $E$, i.e., we can write $D = p_1+...+p_n$ for $p_i \in E(k)$. Let $C$ be the open complement of $D$ in $E$. It is an affine plane cubic curve.

It is known that for a positive integer $n$, we have a surjective homomorphism $[n] :E(\bar{k}) \rightarrow E(\bar{k})$ and thus an exact sequence $$0 \rightarrow E[n] \rightarrow E \xrightarrow{[n]} E \rightarrow 0.$$

Does this exact sequence hold also for $C$? I know that the Kummer sequence exists for some affine varieties, for example, the torus. I'm just wondering if the cubic law on $C$ would mean that we also have it in this case.

Comment: Your question is unclear because $[n]$ is never a regular map on $E-P_1,\ldots,P_m$ (unless it is purely inseparable, like the Frobenius in characteristic $p$). Also there is one group law (defined over $k$) per point $\in E(k)$ (the obtained group varieties are all isomorphic over $k$).

Comment: @reuns Ok thanks for pointing that out. Do you know if there is any similar exact sequence that we could work with the group law on a plane cubic? Can we even consider torsion points?

Comment: I don't understand your problem, why are you affraid of $E$ ? It has several affine models, with a few missing points, usually (in characteristic not $2$) only the point $O$ and a model $y^2=x^3+ax+b$. When you remove more than one point it will usually not be a "plane cubic".

Comment: @reuns Not afraid, but I'm studying obstruction sets on a genus one smooth affine curve. I know that their compactification is either an elliptic curve or some projective curve corresponding to a non-trivial $k$-torsor under its Jacobian. It's not efficient to translate problems directly from that of $E$, because $E$ is proper and naturally satisfies many "nice" properties. Thanks anyway, the part where removing more than 1 point usually wouldn't give us a plane cubic was particularly helpful, I didn't know that! I'll change my approach accordingly.

Comment: @reuns By translation, if we only remove one point we could always assume its $O$, and like you said, end up with the affine model $y^2=x^3+ax+b$. In this case, would multiplication-by-$n$ maps be regular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplication by $n$ is never regular on $E-P_1,\ldots,P_r$

(unless $n=0$ or $n$ has trivial kernel, ie. $n=\pm 1$ or $char(k)=p$, $n=p^l$ and $E$ supersingular)

because $\{ Q\in E, \exists m, [n^m]Q \in P_1,\ldots,P_r\}$ is an infinite set so you'd need to remove infinitely many points to make $[n]$ regular on $E-P_1,\ldots,P_r$.

Comment: Thanks, that was clear.